# $ f: X \rightarrow R^n$ continuous then the set $M=\{x\in X:f(x) \ne 0\} $ is an open set.

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $ f: X \rightarrow R^n$ continuous, where $ (X, d) $ is an arbitrary metric space. Prove or give a counterexample for the assertion that the set $M=\{x\in X:f(x) \ne 0\} $ is an open set.

I'm thinking this might be fake. In the discret metric it seems true. So I'm thinking of an any metric $d$ and for the special case with $ X = \mathbb {R} $ and $ n = 1 $.

I thought for the following functions:

1) $ f (x) = x \Longrightarrow M = (- \infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty) $. This set is opened.

2) $ f (x) = x ^ 2 \Longrightarrow M $ is an open set.

So I conclude that if the roots of $ f $ is a finite quantity, we have that $ M $ is open. Now if it is an infinite contable quantity, for example for $ f (x) = \sin x $, we have that $ M $ will be open.

So I thought of the following function
$$
f (x) = x \sin \left(\dfrac {1} {x}  \right), x \neq 0 \; \mbox {and} \; \;
f(x)=0, x = 0.
$$

The roots of this function get closer and closer to zero because the roots $ x \neq 0 $ are of the form $ x = \dfrac {1} {2k}$ with $ k \in \mathbb {Z} $.
I thought I would have a counterexample here because I know I have points of $ M $ and points of $ \mathbb{R} \backslash M $ each time closer to each other. But I have not been able to conclude that this is indeed a counterexample.

Comment: Did you know that if $f : Y \to Z$ is a continuous function and if $B$ is any open subset of $Z$, then $f^{-1}(B)$ is an open subset of $Y$ (this is taken as the definition of continuity in abstract topology, and is easy to prove using the metric definition of continuity). Now take $B = R^n \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @Rob Arthan I got it. Thanks too much!!! Then this result is true and I understand the proof. I was thinking this is not true and and my attention was only on that. So, thanks too much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$M = f^{-1} \left( \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace \right)$$

is open as the preimage of the open set $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ by the continuous application $f$.